# How did "Jack" (the narrator) manage to attract people to join Fight Club?

Tags: plot-explanation, fight-club

In Fight Club <s>"Jack"</s> (the narrator) and Tyler Durden pick a fight behind the bar and through that fight they manage to attract people to first join the fight and then after founding Fight Club, to join the club.

> As we proceed through the film we realize that Jack and Tyler are actually one person.

The catch here is that, how did he manage to get those people start fighting?

> I mean by beating himself up he looks more like a lunatic than a badass.

Comment: A lunatic can still be quite interresting or even appealing to certain people ;) Nice question though.

Comment: Yes, you got that right. But in that case those people should've started beating themselves up not fighting each other. :)

Comment: If by "Jack" you mean the narrator I have to correct you. The narrator has no name, he's even credited as "narrator".

Comment: You're essentially right, but I don't remember where I saw an article referring to the `narrator` as `Jack`.

Comment: @siebz0r +10 Now finally somebody who realizes that reading an article written in the first person doesn't magically turn you into the protagonist in real life.

Comment: "The narrator" is called Tyler Durden. He has airline ticket stubs with that name on which would require photo ID, he directly asks marla what his name is. He's "The Narrator" because SPOLIERS

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think it was the argument more than the fighting that attracted them.  Remember Tyler's philosophy is "self-improvement is like masturbation, but self-destruction is good" or something like that.  If he was beating himself up, and then told other people that philosophy, it's easy to see how a club dedicated to self-destruction and the Tyler Durden philosophy came together.

Comment: The quote is "self-improvement is like masturbation, but self-destruction..." (smirky look)

Comment: @NilsMunch that was an improvement from the book version that ran: _Maybe self-improvement isn't the answer. Maybe self-destruction is the answer._

Answer (score 21):

The first time you see the fight, some people look at them because they're interested in the fight, and then later ask him if they could have a go one time.

Then later, when it turns out he was beating himself up, it still makes sense actually, because it's still a valid reason for them to go looking at him, and also to ask if they could have a go (in this second case meaning punching him). When the first fight started it all makes sense as in the first case actually.

That's what I thought of it at least.

Answer (score 0):

The movie shows he made people fight each other, but I guess it's used as a metaphor to face all the struggles that we face in our lives. So basically he got people who were bored of their mundane lives and showed them to fight against their struggles. I mean that's what the movie is about.